# Wireless Printer Security

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, security, printer, canon-pixma

I just set up a Canon MX340 on my local network.  The printer is setup in "wireless" mode so that wireless devices can hit it.  I have people on my network that I don't want to be able to print - can I set up any Windows Authentication on top of this so that only some users may connect to the wireless printer?  Thanks.

Comment: How does this printer do its networking? Its own client software, HomeGroup sharing, etc.?

Comment: It must be it's own client software, so that is why I have no idea what I have control over.  It is not a Windows Share for sure.

Answer (score 0):

What about a print server with IP restrictions?

This is a [Printserver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_server). 
A thing like this [hp printserver](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&q=print+server+buy&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=12720511984744757889&ei=uOJTTdjvK4SEOqrgmMIJ&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDIQ8wIwAw#)

Comment: How would I go about doing this?  I am afraid I don't know what you mean.   Thanks.